What is the meaning of "killer of giants" in Ozzy Osbourne's song?
In Ozzy Osbourne's song "Killer of giants" there is expression "killer of giants" in such context:

If none of us believe in war
Then can you tell me, what the weapons for?
Listen to me everyone
If the button is pushed, there'll be nowhere to run, oh


Giants sleeping, giants winning
Wars within their dreams
Till they wake when it's too late
And in God's name blaspheme
Killer of giants, threatens us all


Killer of giants, threatens us all
Mountains of madness
Standing so tall
Marches of protest
Not stopping the war
Oh, the killer of giants
Oh, the killer of giants
Killer of giants
Killer of giants

What is the meaning of "killer of giants"? Is it killer who kill giants or is it killer who giant?
Thanks.

We don't get into interpretation of song lyrics since it's a matter of opinion and off-topic. But "killer of giants" in form is an epithet.  It could be used as a descriptor for David, who slew Goliath, say, or of Jack the Giant Killer in the fairy tale.  One who killed a giant.  You don't have to slay more than one giant to be called "killer of giants". Presumably if you have dispatched one, you can dispatch another.

@TimR Ok. Thanks! Your opinion is interesting!

@TimR But why "killer of giants threatens us all"?

... Tim would doubtless have commented further if this was at all clear, definitively deducible. It's not; speculation is considered off-topic on ELU.

@TimR Jack the Giant Killer did kill several giants.  Perhaps you were thinking of Jack and the Beanstalk.

@Henry I was actually defending application of the epithet to David.  ;-)

[literature.se] is probably a better place to ask questions like this.
